# Is there anyway in which I can create an RSS Feed out of a Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, rss

I have a site which uses Wordpress, i want to be able to create a self hosted RSS feed through Wordpress which includes all the items that have been posted on the page (through WP Aggrator) which have the item attribute feed-item. An example of the pages HTML is shown below, thanks

http://fresharsenal.com/player-ratings-dynamo-zagreb-2-1-arsenal/'>Player Ratings: Dinamo Zagreb 2-1 ArsenalSource: Fresh ArsenalPublished on 2015-09-178 mins ago

Comment: RSS feeds are part of WordPress by default: http://fresharsenal.com/feed/

Answer (score 0):

and you have a feed for each category, tag, author, comments on a page... even search
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Comment: hi there not actually Wordpress posts, this is an example of the page - footballnewsdaily . net / arsenal